# como obtengo el nombre de un archivo tipo part

Tags: java, jsp

Envio un archivo desde un jsp a un servlet alli lo recibo en un getPart pero no puedo ni obtener el nombre de este. asi estoy tomando el archivo, pero me da como resultado null, y ya realize un verificacion y si me esta recibiendo el archivo.

```
 Part archivo = request.getPart("dataDoc");

  String fileName = Paths.get(archivo.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
```

Comment: ¿Has probado `String fileName = archivo.getSubmittedFileName()`?

Comment: en los 2 casos, me sale null el filename